# Debian installation doesn't detect the allocated partition made in Windows

Tags: debian, partition, system-installation, dual-boot

I have windows 10 and want to install Linux with windows 10, meaning two separate OS on same computer, so I have Unallocated 103 GB disk space to install Linux on it [Hardisk showing 103GB free](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UvoRo.png)

The issue is that these unallocated space doesn't appear in Debian-install loader window [debian install loader doesn't show the 103GB](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OjS3F.jpg).

Please note that I am running the Debian install loader using USB that includes the content of downloaded ISO file, it isn't the live USB it is full installation.

Why the 103GB do not appear? 
Please help what can I do?

If possible a solution without deleting and reinstalling Windows.

Failed suggestion:
Tried to format the drive to exFAT as suggested by GAD3R and still seeing the same picture the 103GB didn't appear.

Comment: I believe the issue is that you have a _dynamic_ disk, which isn't really partitioned in the same way as non-Windows systems expect

Comment: What I should do then?

Comment: Please edit your title to something more relevant to the problem. Perhaps something like "Debian installation doesn't detect the allocated partition made in Windows"

Comment: Format it to `exFAT` from windows

Comment: From this link I sent you before about [Dynamic Disks](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa363785(v=vs.85).aspx#dynamic_disks) it says "On MBR partitions, the database is contained in the last 1 megabyte (MB) of the disk." which I see on your second image as the first partition listed.  You might just be looking at backing up your Windows, deleting and reinstalling Windows and keeping the drive as Basic and not Dynamic, then installing Linux.

Comment: @Fox Ignore my last comment.  Oops, looking at OP's second image, the full drive is taken anyway, thus meaning that the Unallocated Space is taken by Dynamic.

Comment: Virtual Box sucks see here why http://askubuntu.com/questions/889353/vbox-failed-in-startup-error-1-failed-to-start-hostname-service-2-failed-to-st?noredirect=1#comment1390197_889353

Comment: @Fox Thanks for your response, I could not find helpful info regarding converting from dynamic to basic do you have? I am not sure how much that conversion is dangerous? have you tried it is it safe? by the way I had to terminate the VirtualBox since it was stuck.

Comment: @Fox can you point me out where did you read that? link?

Comment: @Nizarazo Here's a [link](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc755238(v=ws.11).aspx) to one of the technet articles

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After long research I find a way to convert from dynamic to basic without deleting all partitions by using the program "AOMEI Partition Assistant Pro Edition" here is the link step by step:
http://www.disk-partition.com/windows-10/convert-dynamic-disk-to-basic-windows-10-4348.html

It worked great the disk is converted to basic and I can now see the partition prepared by windows on Debian installer.